# Creating a hardlinked directory loop on a mac

Tags: mac, filesystems

How can I create a hardlinked directory loop on a mac? I just want to do it for fun haha I discovered the concept on [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/981/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not on a device where I can quote the man page, but as I recall, it warns against trying to hard link directories, only lets root *try* to create them, and warns that the filesystem might not even support it.  If you still really want to try, look at the man page for the appropriate option.

---

Here's the relevant option:

```
-d, -F, --directory
       allow the superuser to attempt to hard link  directories  (note:
       will  probably  fail  due  to  system restrictions, even for the
       superuser)
```

Comment: Mac OS X supports directory hardlinks (for Time Machine), but will probably refuse to create loops.